# openGL smoothing lines

Tags: c++, image, opengl, smoothing

I have the following image

[image]

and I'd like the lines to be smooth, how can I achieve this? I'm using openGL on a desktop Windows app. I noticed that webGL equivalent is smoothed. I tried subsurfing with blender (increasing the number of polygons) but that didn't work.

The easier the solution, the better I'll understand it

Comment: Maybe you need to enable antialiasing.

Comment: This may be handy: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html#name2

Comment: I tried them all but none of them did anything visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this:

http://www.qtforum.org/article/22515/multisample-aa-in-a-qglwidget.html

Comment: You should accept your own answer if this solved your problem sufficiently.

Comment: You're of course right, I didn't pay attention to your posting time - sorry about that!